# Changing Data Types in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I've got lots of tables with 2 columns each, always using 2 data types: Text and Memo.

There is a series of Appends, Deletes and Selects functioning, but now I need to transform these MEMO types to Text and Number. Is there a way to refactor the database entirely?

I'm afraid of changing anything manually and affect the queries that exist.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring the database will quite likely require reworking all the queries anyways, but in order to prevent stuff from being broken in the interim, the best way I can think of would be to create new tables that will be the refactored tables, 
do INSERT INTO statements to convert the old data to the new tables, and then start re-connecting everything to the new tables, taking advantage of the refactoring.